# Populate a Object with random Objects, and setting specific properties in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I am using NodeJS and socket.io to create an Online Browser Card Game.

I have written the code at the bottom, in which an Object gets populated with two Players (0 and 1), each of those then gets an Object which holds the deck, and in that, there are two more Objects, that hold the Cards in forms of Object.

```
userlists: { // I have more than just "g" in here, but for this part, only "g" is needed
    "g": { // Holds the different game-sessions
        "roomid": { // A Game-Session
            "Players": { // Contains the 2 Opponents
                0: { // Opponent 1
                    "deck": { // The deck of Opponent 1 (note that the different decks are no objects, though if needed, they could be)
                        "onHand": [ // Contains all the Cards "on-Hand"
                            {
                                "Type": "Knight",
                                ... // more properties
                                "position": 0 // The position of the Card on the hand of the Player
                            },
                            ... // more Cards
                        ],
                        "inBlock": [ // Contains all the reserve-Cards
                            ... // as in ["onHand"], but with ["position"]=null
                        ]
                    }
                },
                1: { // Opponent 2
                    ... // same as Opponent 1, just different deck of course
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But as this is a question, the code beneath does not actually produce the desired result. It will in fact, at first, output the wanted numbers, but then, at the point, where it gets sent (`function snddcks()`) to the Client, `"position"` (and actually all other properties too), get somewhat copied as per `"Type"`, so all `"Type":"Knight"`'s would have `"position":0` and so on.

And that is the problem, where I just can't figure out why it actually happens.

At last, I'll just quickly explain the process:

1. well, first of all, the player, who joins (it's NR 1, not 0), creates the game-session-object (server-side) in `userlists["g"][roomid]`, where roomid is a random-generated string
2. NR1, then tells NR0 that he has joined, who then sends back "playerhasjoined" to the server
3. on server-side then, the function "populateDeck" gets called, which then populates the deck, first for NR0, and then for NR1
4. at the end, "snddcks" gets called, which then sends all the data to both of the clients

So in step 3, all the "position" and other properties are set correctly, but in step 4, they get overwritten, by whatsoever.

Here's the NEW Code:

```
function joingid() {
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.join(roomid);
    socket.leave("lobby");
    socket.leave("searching");

    socket.emit("playerfound", {
        gid: roomid
    });
    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('playerjoined', {
        usr: socket.username,
        gid: roomid
    });
}
socket.on('playerhasjoined', function(data) {
    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.leave("lobby");

    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('otheropponent', {
        usr: socket.username
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        populateDeck2(roomid, data["oppo"]);
    }, 500);
});

function gRC(roomid, i, i2) {
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["onHand"][i] = standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)).toString();
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["position"] = i;
}
function gRCc(roomid, i, i2) {
    return function() {
        gRC(roomid, i, i2);
    };
}
function gRC2(roomid, i, i2) {
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["inBlock"][i] = standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["inBlock"][i]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)).toString();
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][i2]["deck"]["inBlock"][i]["position"] = i;
}
function gRCc2(roomid, i, i2) {
    return function() {
        gRC2(roomid, i, i2);
    };
}
function gRC2_1(roomid, a1i, a2i, card) {
    return function() {
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1i]["deck"]["onHand"].push(card);
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1i]["deck"]["onHand"][a2i]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)).toString();
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1i]["deck"]["onHand"][a2i]["position"] = a2i;
    };
}
function populateDeck2(roomid, oppo) {
    var oppos = [socket.username, oppo];
    userlists["g"][roomid] = {
        "RoomID": roomid,
        "Players": {
            0: {
                "Player": socket.username,
                "deck": {
                    "onHand": [],
                    "onField": [],
                    "inBlock": []
                },
                "MP-Left": 20
            },
            1: {
                "Player": oppo,
                "deck": {
                    "onHand": [],
                    "onField": [],
                    "inBlock": []
                },
                "MP-Left": 20
            }
        },
        "Creationdate": Date().toString(),
        "Winner": null,
        "currentPlayer": oppos[Math.floor(Math.random() * oppos.length)],
        "roundNR": 0
    };
    for (var a1 = 0; a1 < 2; a1++) { // plnr
        for (var a2 = 0; a2 < 5; a2++) { // onHand
            (function() {
                gRCc(roomid, a2, a1)();
            })();

            // gRC2_1(roomid, a1, a2, gRC())();

            // (function() {
            //     var card1 = gRC();
            //     userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"].push(card1);
            //     userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"][a2]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)).toString();
            //     userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"][a2]["position"] = a2;
            //     console.log("@"+a1+"::"+a2+" >> "+userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"][a2]["CID"]+" AND "+userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"][a2]["position"]);
            // })();
        }
        for (var a3 = 0; a3 < 50; a3++) { // inBlock
            (function() {
                gRCc2(roomid, a3, a1)();
            })();

            // (function() {
            //     userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["inBlock"].push(gRC());
            //     userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["inBlock"][a3]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)).toString();
            // })();
        }
        fs.writeFile("userlistsLOG_1.log", "ONE: "+a1+""+Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][a1]["deck"]["onHand"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error happened during writing to log')
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }
    SP("gamepage.html", function FNCr(CALLBACKf) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".gameid").html(roomid);
            $(".opponent").html(opponent);
            $(".giveupbutton").on('click', function() {
                socket.emit('giveup');
            });
            $(".get_g_button").on('click', function() {
                socket.emit('get_g', {
                    gid: roomid
                });
            });

            $("#PAGETITLE").html("Da_Cards: VS "+opponent);
            // socket.emit("rcvsrlst");

            typeof CALLBACKf === 'function' && CALLBACKf();
        }, 1500);
    }, "aiI", roomid);
    SCL("gamepage loaded", "", "aiI", roomid);

    snddcks();
    snddcks(true);
}

function snddcks(oppo) {
    var oppo = oppo || false;
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];
    if (oppo === true) {
        socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks into "+roomid);
        fs.writeFile("userlistsLOG_2.log", "TWO 1: "+Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error happened during writing to log')
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    } else if (oppo === false) {
        socket.emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks to "+socket.username);
        fs.writeFile("userlistsLOG_2.log", "TWO 0: "+Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error happened during writing to log')
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }

    // setTimeout(function() {
    //     // fs.writeFileSync("userlistsLOG.log", Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"});
    //     // fs.writeFileSync("userlistsLOG.log", Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"});
    // }, 100);
}
```

Here's the OLD Code:

```
function joingid() {
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.join(roomid);
    socket.leave("lobby");
    socket.leave("searching");

    socket.emit("playerfound", {
        gid: roomid
    });
    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('playerjoined', {
        usr: socket.username,
        gid: roomid
    });

    userlists["g"][roomid] = {
        "RoomID": roomid,
        "Players": {},
        "Creationdate": Date().toString(),
        "Winner": null,
        "currentPlayer": null,
        "roundNR": 0
    };
}
socket.on('playerhasjoined', function (data) {
    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.leave("lobby");

    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('otheropponent', {
        usr: socket.username
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        populateDeck(roomid, "0", function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                // lgp(function() {
                //     snddcks();
                // });
                populateDeck(roomid, "1", function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        SP("gamepage.html", function FNCr(CALLBACKf) {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                $(".gameid").html(roomid);
                                $(".opponent").html(opponent);
                                $(".giveupbutton").on('click', function () {
                                    socket.emit('giveup');
                                });
                                $(".get_g_button").on('click', function () {
                                    socket.emit('get_g', {
                                        gid: roomid
                                    });
                                });

                                $("#PAGETITLE").html("Da_Cards: VS " + opponent);
                                // socket.emit("rcvsrlst");

                                typeof CALLBACKf === 'function' && CALLBACKf();
                            }, 1500);
                        }, "aiI", roomid);
                        SCL("gamepage loaded", "", "aiI", roomid);

                        snddcks();
                        snddcks(true);

                        // console.error("THE ROOMID IS "+roomid.toString());
                        // lgp(roomid, function() {
                        //     console.error("THE ROOMID IS "+roomid.toString());
                        //     snddcks(true);
                        // });
                    }, 100);
                });
            }, 100);
        });
    }, 100);
});

function gCA(mode, i, im, roomid, plnr, callback) {
    if (mode === "1r") {
        return standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
    } else if (mode === "pop_onHand") {
        if (i < im) {
            var card = standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];

            // var randI = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000000) + 1)).toString();
            var randI = "CID_" + i.toString();

            card["CID"] = randI;
            // card["position"] = i;
            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"].push(card);
            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["position"] = i;
            console.log("1_" + plnr + " :: " + userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["CID"] + " with " + userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["position"] + " and " + card["position"]);
            // userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"].push(socket.card);
            // console.log((i+" and "+card["position"])+" and "+userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][i]["position"]+" and "+plnr);

            i++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                gCA("pop_onHand", i, 5, roomid, plnr, callback);
            }, 150);
        } else if (i === im) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                gCA("pop_inBlock", 0, 50, roomid, plnr, callback);
            }, 150);
        }
    } else if (mode === "pop_inBlock") {
        if (i < im) {
            var card2 = standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["inBlock"].push(card2);
            console.log(i + " :: " + userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["inBlock"][i]["position"]);

            i++;
            setTimeout(function () {
                gCA("pop_inBlock", i, 50, roomid, plnr, callback);
            }, 150);
        } else if (i === im) {
            for (var j = 0; j < userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"].length; j++) {
                console.log("2_" + plnr + " :: " + userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][j]["CID"] + " with " + userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][j]["position"]);
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
            }, 50);
        }
    }
}

function gRC() {
    return standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
}

function gCA2(roomid, plnr, callback) {
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"];
}

function populateDeck(roomid, plnr, callback) {
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr] = {
        "Player": socket.username,
        "deck": null,
        "MP-Left": 20
    };

    // Hier könnten nachher dann noch die gekauften Karten und so eingefügt werden,
    // bzw. dat vorgefertigte Deck usw.
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"] = {
        "onHand": [],
        "onField": [],
        "inBlock": []
    };

    // gCA("pop_onHand", 0, 5, roomid, plnr, callback);
    var k1 = 0;
    (function loop1() {
        if (k1 < 5) {
            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"].push(gRC());
            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][k1]["position"] = k1;
            k1++;
            loop1();
        } else {
            var k2 = 0;
            (function loop2() {
                if (k2 < 50) {
                    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["inBlock"].push(gRC());
                    k2++;
                    loop2();
                } else {
                    var k3 = 0;
                    (function loop3() {
                        if (k3 < 5) {
                            userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][plnr]["deck"]["onHand"][k3]["position"] = k3;
                            k3++;
                            loop3();
                        } else {
                            setTimeout(function () {
                                typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
                            }, 50);
                        }
                    }());
                }
            }());
        }
    }());
}

function snddcks(oppo) {
    var oppo = oppo || false;
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];
    if (userlists["g"][roomid]["Setup"] === false) {
        var k5 = 0;
        (function loop5() {
            if (k5 < 5) {
                userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"][k5]["position"] = k5;
                k5++;
                loop5();
            } else {
                var k6 = 0;
                (function loop6() {
                    if (k6 < 5) {
                        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"][k6]["position"] = k6;
                        k6++;
                        loop6();
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            typeof callback === 'function' && callback();
                        }, 50);
                    }
                }());
            }
        }());
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Setup"] = true;
    }
    if (oppo === true) {
        socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks into " + roomid);
    } else if (oppo === false) {
        socket.emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks to " + socket.username);
    }

    setTimeout(function () {
        fs.writeFileSync("userlistsLOG.log", Date().toString() + ":\n" + JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"]) + "\n\n", {
            flag: "a"
        })
        // fs.writeFileSync("userlistsLOG.log", Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"});
        // fs.writeFileSync("userlistsLOG.log", Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"});
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: What is this timeout thing on the serverside needed for ?
Any why do you iterate recursively ?

Comment: As much as I understood, NodeJS is pretty much completly asynchronous.
Also, (I don't quite remember though) the timeout's where actually needed, because the clients wouldn't receive specific data's before others..

Comment: It is JS with some libraries in a runtime environment. Just not in the browser. There is no reason to have functions for trivial iterations ... Try to rewrite your loops.
And do not use timeouts before a method invocation. Makes no sense. Only if you need to wait for a non blocking source and estimate the threshold. But this would be dangerous ...

Comment: @LemmyTauer would you then recommend me, using for- or while-loops, or is there another cleaner way to do it? Because in `loop5` and `6` actually are not needed, but I just put them into `snddcks`, to test, if it actually changes anything. But apparently it didn't..

Also, all of that code, is actually server-side, so it's NodeJS, and when you just google "is node js async ?", then you will get many results, pointing out to Node's Asynchronous nature. Or am I still getting smthng wrong here!?

Comment: Go with a for loop and beware of Closures you create and thus will likely change "locally scoped" copies of your data ...
So either preserve by passing this to a function scope during invocation(needs some more understanding of closures) or try to avoid to much nesting with callbacks ...

Comment: I edited the question, with the new "for-loop"-Code-thingy.
But I just don't get it with those closures, and I was on several sites, that only explained them, using functions, but no objects :|

So I don't quite understand what I am getting wrong all the time.. (Also the cards "inHand" now actually get copied from those of "inBlock", so I have one more "closure-problem" or whatever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!!
I just solved my problem though it took me like 3 days..
So many many thanks to @LemmyTauer for the helpful comments :)

Here's the interesting Code-Part:

```
function generatedeckthigieandreturn(number) {
    var arr;
    arr = [];
    var fncs;
    fncs = [];
    var ARRAYTHINGIEd = [];

    function gRC() {
        console.log("gRC called");
        return standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
    }

    for (var a = 0; a < number; a++) {
        console.log(a);
        fncs[a] = function(b) {
            console.log(a+" called");
            return function() {
                arr[b] = gRC();
                arr[b]["position"] = b;
                arr[b]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 900) + 100)).toString();
                console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[b], null, 4));
                return JSON.stringify(arr[b]);
            }
        };
    }
    for (var c = 0; c < number; c++) {
        ARRAYTHINGIEd.push(JSON.parse(fncs[c](c)()));
    }
    return ARRAYTHINGIEd;
}
for (var xa = 0; xa < 2; xa++) {
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][xa]["deck"]["onHand"] = generatedeckthigieandreturn(5);
    userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][xa]["deck"]["inBlock"] = generatedeckthigieandreturn(50);
}
```

So in the end, I used `JSON.stringify()` to preserve the Card-Object, and and `JSON.parse()` to get it back to "normal" format.

And here's the "complete fixed question"-Code:

```
function joingid() {
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.join(roomid);
    socket.leave("lobby");
    socket.leave("searching");

    socket.emit("playerfound", {
        gid: roomid
    });
    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('playerjoined', {
        usr: socket.username,
        gid: roomid
    });
}
socket.on('playerhasjoined', function(data) {
    socket.state = "playing";
    socket.leave("lobby");

    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];

    socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('otheropponent', {
        usr: socket.username
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        populateDeck2(roomid, data["oppo"]);
    }, 500);
});


function populateDeck2(roomid, oppo) {
    var oppos = [socket.username, oppo];
    userlists["g"][roomid] = {
        "RoomID": roomid,
        "Players": {
            0: {
                "Player": socket.username,
                "deck": {
                    "onHand": [],
                    "onField": [],
                    "inBlock": []
                },
                "MP-Left": 20
            },
            1: {
                "Player": oppo,
                "deck": {
                    "onHand": [],
                    "onField": [],
                    "inBlock": []
                },
                "MP-Left": 20
            }
        },
        "Creationdate": Date().toString(),
        "Winner": null,
        "currentPlayer": oppos[Math.floor(Math.random() * oppos.length)],
        "roundNR": 0
    };

    function generatedeckthigieandreturn(number) {
        var arr;
        arr = [];
        var fncs;
        fncs = [];
        var ARRAYTHINGIEd = [];

        function gRC() {
            console.log("gRC called");
            return standardDeckCards[Math.floor(Math.random() * standardDeckCards.length)];
        }

        for (var a = 0; a < number; a++) {
            console.log(a);
            fncs[a] = function(b) {
                console.log(a+" called");
                return function() {
                    arr[b] = gRC();
                    arr[b]["position"] = b;
                    arr[b]["CID"] = "CID-"+(Math.floor((Math.random() * 900) + 100)).toString();
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr[b], null, 4));
                    return JSON.stringify(arr[b]);
                }
            };
        }
        for (var c = 0; c < number; c++) {
            ARRAYTHINGIEd.push(JSON.parse(fncs[c](c)()));
        }
        return ARRAYTHINGIEd;
    }
    for (var xa = 0; xa < 2; xa++) {
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][xa]["deck"]["onHand"] = generatedeckthigieandreturn(5);
        userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][xa]["deck"]["inBlock"] = generatedeckthigieandreturn(50);
    }

    SP("gamepage.html", function FNCr(CALLBACKf) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".gameid").html(roomid);
            $(".opponent").html(opponent);
            $(".giveupbutton").on('click', function() {
                socket.emit('giveup');
            });
            $(".get_g_button").on('click', function() {
                socket.emit('get_g', {
                    gid: roomid
                });
            });

            $("#PAGETITLE").html("Da_Cards: VS "+opponent);
            // socket.emit("rcvsrlst");

            typeof CALLBACKf === 'function' && CALLBACKf();
        }, 1500);
    }, "aiI", roomid);
    SCL("gamepage loaded", "", "aiI", roomid);

    snddcks();
    snddcks(true);
}

function snddcks(oppo) {
    var oppo = oppo || false;
    var roomid = userlists["eo"][socket.username]["gid"];
    if (oppo === true) {
        socket.broadcast.to(roomid).emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks into "+roomid);
        fs.writeFile("userlistsLOG_2.log", "TWO 1: "+Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error happened during writing to log')
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    } else if (oppo === false) {
        socket.emit('snddcks', {
            "d0_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["MP-Left"],
            "d0_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"],
            "d0_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d0_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
            "d1_MP-Left": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["MP-Left"],
            "d1_onHand": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onHand"].length,
            "d1_onField": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["onField"],
            "d1_inBlockC": userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][1]["deck"]["inBlock"].length,
        });
        console.log("Sent decks to "+socket.username);
        fs.writeFile("userlistsLOG_2.log", "TWO 0: "+Date().toString()+":\n"+JSON.stringify(userlists["g"][roomid]["Players"][0]["deck"]["onHand"])+"\n\n", {flag:"a"}, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('error happened during writing to log')
                return console.log(err)
            }
        });
    }
```